# WTForms doesn't validate the input

Tags: python-3.x

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=10)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[InputRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[InputRequired(), EqualTo(password)])
    remember = BooleanField("Remember Me")
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")



@app.route("/register/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Account created for ' + form.username.data + '!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        print("not valid")
    return render_template("register.html", title = "Register", form = form)
```

'''It produces following errors: 
{'email': ['This field is required.'], 'confirm_password': ["Invalid field name ']})>'."]}'''

'''
I am new to Flask and python in general so, i apologize in advance if problem is obvious. Thanks for you time.'''

Comment: the second part of code is in a different file, everything works fine except the validation part

Comment: Sorry for bad grammer and spellings

Answer (score 0):

it appears you're following corey schafer's FLASK tutorial (it (and Corey Schafer) is a great resource).

In my code, instead of InputRequired() I use DataRequired(), and it works well. let me know if you are still working on this.